# Why dont some users not able to see the related list links on the top of the page

Tags: administration

I have some users who are not able to see the related list links on the top of the page. The related list are visible on the pagelayouts but not the links.

Any thoughts on how to change it?

Comment: is this a VF page?

Comment: No, i was refering to hover links. Thanks Simon for letting us know what its called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links you are talking about are these, right:

[image: hoverlinks]

They are called the Hover Links, and can be disabled on a specific user by turning on "Accessibility mode"

Get them to click **"My Name" > Personal Settings > Display & Layout** and turn off accessibility (if on) - this is the most common causing of missing hover boxes/links I am aware of.

Here:

[image: settings]

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) . Never knew they are called hover links